# Googel Apps Script Test Deployment - "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again."

Tags: google-apps-script, ide

I have created a number of tools with Google Apps Script, using Google Sheets as a database.  Since the move to the new IDE (which I really like), I've seen a new error that I had never seen before.

On two (and so far only two) of the tools I've created, when I go to do a Test Deployment, the new window shows an error message: "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again."

When this happened to the first tool, I did some research, and saw mentions of this happening when more than one user logged into a Script project.  That was a possibility for my situation, as I had been in that sheet/project with different usernames.  However, everything I had read indicated it was an issue with the Production Deployment; I didn't see anything related to a Test Deployment error.  The only solve I had for this was to start a whole new Project and copy the code over.

Now I am seeing this issue on a second project, but it's one that only one user has ever accessed.  Initially, it was reported by one of my users who was getting that message on the Production Deployment.  When I go into the Project to do a Test Deployment, I'm getting the same error.  In Production, it appears to have resolved itself (mostly), as the tool is working again, but it's been up and down some this morning.  And even with the Prod Deployment working, I am still unable to run a Test Deployment.

This is not something I ever ran into with the legacy editor.  Has anyone else seen this sort of behavior since the new Editor was released?  Any thoughts on how this can be resolved, short of creating a whole new project for this specific tool?

Comment: I'm not so sure it has any to do with you personally. I was experiencing the same thing yesterday.  I had been using Drive API pretty heavily so I just took a break and came back later and the problem seemed to go away.

Comment: Same issue for me, especially last night (pacific time). I keep retryihg and eventually it seems to work. I don't think it has anything to do with your code. I like the new editor, but I've noticed this more frequently compared to the legacy editor.

Comment: Thank you both Cooper and PGSSystemTester.  I'm glad to know that it's not just me.  And yes, I really like the new editor, but have run into a couple small things.

Comment: I think it will turn out to be a great editor.  I like the wrap feature and having the execution log below the code.  I think having the huge menu of command available at a click. But I miss not having  access to Script  Properties so that I can view them, although I could do that myself.  And I had grown comfortable with having a lot of support links in the help but it's much nicer at correctly formatting arrow function than the old editor.  Any way I've seen a lot change in the 4 years since I've been volunteering here and I've learned a lot.

Comment: I get that @Cooper.  I am by no means a developer; I just play one in our PMO, so I'm always a glad to see that other are having the same issues I am.  I think it'll be a good editor too.  I'm glad they finally added collapsible code; that's a big help.  The variable and function names coming up for autocomplete is great.  And I'm sure there are things that I'll continue to find.  But if all I ever get is 500 Errors when running a Test Deployment ... well that's less than great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue has already been reported in the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/177561485) as a potential bug:

[image]

There seems to be a workaround though, posted by the OP:

[image]

You can also star the request to make the issue more visible:

[image]

Note that if the steps are different, you also have the option to file a separate ticket in the Issue Tracker.

Comment: Thank you @carlos-m for the link to the google issue.  I have added a comment there now as well.  While the project that I initially experienced this on this morning seems to be resolved, other projects I am working on are still having this issue.  Hopefully, the folks at Google will be able to identify and solve this issue.